# How to get ?text=[content] into text area.

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

So on twitter it is possible to put content into the tweet text area onload by putting text if front of ?text=

Ex:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello world
```

The url above will put hello world in the text area. How can i do this?
I havent found any similar question about this on stackoverflow or any other site.

If i'm breaking any rules or etiquette by posting this please comment below and i'll remove this question immediately. I'm still fairly new and i dont know how stack overflow works/

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET['text']; ?>` should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it safely (protecting against XSS attacks):

```
<textarea name="mytext"><?php echo(htmlentities($_GET['text'])); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to put the output into a text area?